# Ubuntu One - u1sdtool - slow and not responsive

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, lubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu 11.10 on my new system. I want to use Ubuntu One within the terminal, so I tried it with *u1sdtool*.

If I try `u1sdtool --version`, it took almost a minute to get a result *(version 2.0.0)*.

If I try `u1sdtool --status`, I get an error:

```
Oops, an error ocurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

On the other side, if I put some file in the */home/user/Ubuntu One* directory, it is synchronized with the cloud (and vice verse).

I would like to use Ubuntu One service, but it is slow and not responsive. It should also have a percentage indicator (for large files).

Any idea, what is going on?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!